# Decoding AirPlay Mirroring Protocol

Tags: ios, macos, ipad, airplay, fairplay

I want my app to mirror the display of my iPad 2 to my Mac.

I have published the `_airplay._tcp` service and am listening on the port `7100`. The app shows in the `AirPlay` menu and the `Mirroring` option is also there. Video and audio streaming work perfectly.

But I don't know how to decode the FairPlay encryption (`POST /fp-setup`) to support AirPlay mirroring. I have taken reference from http://www.aorensoftware.com/blog/2011/08/20/exploring-airplay-mirroring-internals/. If anyone has any idea on how to do that, please tell me.

Comment: This question is currently intractable, because the exact specifications of FairPlay encryption [have not been reverse-engineered by the community](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AirPlay#Protocols). The effort is noble, but in the scope of answering this question, potential answerers will very likely expose themselves (and SO) to significant legal exposure from Apple. I wish you the best of luck in your endeavors, though.

Comment: Any News? It seems that plenty of products eg. Reflections / Airserver and others now have got a workable solution… it would be great to hear if either of you have got anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check out AirServer -> they've already done this and it works flawlessly (almost)..

Comment: +1: AirServer works just fine. For presentations, etc. really helpful.

Comment: does someone have airserver code or some link that may give some idea how it works?

Answer (score 1):

They are using AES encryption, -- partially right.
But very long code in fp-setup handshaking,(First FP-SETUP, Second FP-SETUP, fpaeskey encryption) and also the real decryption part is Apple's customized module.